# Can these tracks be grouped under one Electronic music subgenre?

Tags: electronic-music, identify-this-genre

I'd like to identify the exact subgenre of the following tracks for a DJ set I'm developing. I feel I'd dance exactly the same way to each of these tracks. I'd like to find other DJ sets that sound similar, for inspiration.

1. [Berlin by Modeselektor ft. Miss Platnum](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PQbIfznortE)
2. [Embody by SebastiAn](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=awtiZEiiAE8)
3. [Blue Jeans (RAC mix) by Lana Del Rey](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iqdXeHN6cZA)
4. [I Follow Rivers (Magician remix) by Lykke Li](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3FXMsoTTcog)
5. [Electric Feel (Justice remix) by MGMT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AWigCggVv2Y)

The following [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_electronic_music_genres) lists hundreds of potential subgenres of Electronic music. Maybe one of these fits?

Comment: Hi Kanayt, and welcome to our site!  I changed your question back to one more similar to your original version, because that one was actually a better fit.  The addition of the Pandora material was just confusing.

Answer (score 0):

To say "identify the exact subgenre" somewhat suggests that tracks/songs/compositions go in one specific subgenre, while in reality there's little consensus on what (sub)genres exist, what they're called and what their characteristics would be.

Having said that, I'd say your selection could go under "indy disco" or "indie dance" (especially 1, 2 and 5) without too much heated discussion.

I suggest looking up Ed Banger Records and Monkeytown Records if you're into this sound.

Finding music via artists/producers and their labels generally yields better results than looking up Djs. Other than that you can see what music/artists links where on sites like Bandcamp.com and Soundcloud.com. Happy hunting!